# Access usestate when using functional component React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using a functional component to create a card component. Now I want to make use of React.usestate to open a dialogue box when clicking on a button, something like this: onClick {handleOpen}.
The problem is, I am not sure where to place the usestate block, because when placed outside of the component, the whole page won't render, but I can't figure out where to place it inside of the component. I am new to react and still confused, hope this makes sense!

```
 
const GroupCard: FC<Group> = ({
  name,
  date,
  description,
  users,
  interests,
}

) => (


  <Card sx={{ width: '350px', marginBottom: '100px' }}>
    <CardHeader title={name} />

    <Stack
      direction="row"
      spacing={1}
      sx={{
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }}
    >
      {interests.map((interest) => (
        <Chip color="success" label={interest} />
      ))}
    </Stack>

    <p>
      {description}
    </p>

    <p>
      {users.length + 1}
      {' '}
      members
    </p>
    <p>{date}</p>


    <Grid container justifyContent="center" >
      <Grid item xs={"auto"} sm={"auto"} md={"auto"} justifyContent="space-around" >
        <Button onClick={handleOpen} variant="contained" size="small" style={{ background: '#018749' }} >
          Join group
        </Button>
        <Modal
          open={open}
          onClose={handleClose}
          aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
          aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
        >
          <Box sx={style}>
            <Typography
              id="modal-modal-title"
              variant="h6"
              component="h2"
            >
              You have been added to this group.
            </Typography>
          </Box>
        </Modal>
      </Grid>

      <Grid item xs={"auto"} sm="auto" md="auto" justifyContent="space-between" >
        <Button variant="contained" size="small" style={{ background: '#018749' }} >
          View profile
        </Button>
      </Grid>

      <Grid item xs={"auto"} sm="auto" md="auto" justifyContent="space-between" >
        <Button variant="contained" size="small" style={{ background: '#018749' }} >
          Match
        </Button>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>

  </Card>
)

// this block needs to be placed somewhere else
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);

export default GroupCard;
```

Comment: The `useState` calls go **inside** the component function.  Usually right at the start of the function.  Then you `return` the JSX markup at the end of the function.

Comment: Any code after a `return` will be ignored in any function, not only functional components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple read of the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) will tell you that you need to place it in the component. You need to utilize curly brace syntax to return your JSX instead of parentheses.

```
const GroupCard: FC<Group> = ({
  name,
  date,
  description,
  users,
  interests,
}

) => {
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);

  return (<Card sx={{ width: '350px', marginBottom: '100px' }}>
    <CardHeader title={name} />

    <Stack
      direction="row"
      spacing={1}
      sx={{
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }}
    >
      {interests.map((interest) => (
        <Chip color="success" label={interest} />
      ))}
    </Stack>

    <p>
      {description}
    </p>

    <p>
      {users.length + 1}
      {' '}
      members
    </p>
    <p>{date}</p>


    <Grid container justifyContent="center" >
      <Grid item xs={"auto"} sm={"auto"} md={"auto"} justifyContent="space-around" >
        <Button onClick={handleOpen} variant="contained" size="small" style={{ background: '#018749' }} >
          Join group
        </Button>
        <Modal
          open={open}
          onClose={handleClose}
          aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
          aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
        >
          <Box sx={style}>
            <Typography
              id="modal-modal-title"
              variant="h6"
              component="h2"
            >
              You have been added to this group.
            </Typography>
          </Box>
        </Modal>
      </Grid>

      <Grid item xs={"auto"} sm="auto" md="auto" justifyContent="space-between" >
        <Button variant="contained" size="small" style={{ background: '#018749' }} >
          View profile
        </Button>
      </Grid>

      <Grid item xs={"auto"} sm="auto" md="auto" justifyContent="space-between" >
        <Button variant="contained" size="small" style={{ background: '#018749' }} >
          Match
        </Button>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>

  </Card>);
}

export default GroupCard;
```

Comment: Thank you!! Forgetting that the docs actually exist sometimes:)